# Construction of sequence satisfying some bound

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Can we construct a sequence of integers $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that,
$$
\frac{1}{4}< \frac{a_n}{n}<\frac{1}{2}, \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\forall n\ge n_0
$$ 
where $n_0$ some integer.

Comment: but an=3n not work

Comment: $$a_n = \min \{ k \in \Bbb Z : \frac{1}{4} < \frac{k}{n} < \frac{1}{2} \}$$

Comment: Think about the number line. There must be some fifths, sixths, sevenths etc. in that interval of length $1/4$. (This is @Crostul 's comment.)

Comment: Choose $n_0  \ge 5$, and $n \ge n_0$, then on any interval of length $>{1 \over 5}$ there is some $p$ such that ${p \over n}$ lies in this interval. Note that ${1 \over 2 }-{1 \over 4} = {1 \over 4} < {1 \over 5}$.

Comment: For $n=3k$ you could explicitly take $a_n=k$

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Note that,

$$\frac 14\lt\frac{a_n}n\lt\frac 12\iff\frac n4\lt a_n\lt\frac n2\tag 1$$

Then, an integer sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfying $(1)$ for all $n\geq 8$ can be given by, $$a_n=\left\lfloor\frac{\frac n4+\frac n2}2\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{3n}8\right\rfloor$$

where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ denotes the floor function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: For $n = 4$ this will give $a_n = 1$ which does not satisfy the inequality.

Comment: @copper.hat, you're right. It seems that it works for $n\geq 8$. Edited!

Comment: I guess it fails for $n\lt 8$ sometimes due to the small gap between the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to check that we must have $n_0 \ge 5$.

If $n_0 \ge 5$, and $n \ge n_0$, then the points ${p \over n}$ are spaced apart by
multiples of ${1 \over n} \le {1 \over n_0} \le {1 \over 5}$ and hence any
closed interval of length $\ge {1 \over 5}$ will contain one of these points.

Now note that $[{11 \over 40}, {19 \over 40}] \subset ({1 \over 4} , {1 \over 2})$ and has length ${ 1\over 5}$.

Hence if we let $a_n = \lceil {11 n \over 40} \rceil$, then ${a_n \over n} \in [{11 \over 40}, {19 \over 40}]$.